# Selenium Python skip NoSuchElementException error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There is a page my teacher is making me do where I am supposed to click on a term and match it to its definition. There are 30 words and there can only be 6 (with their matching definition so a total of 1)of them on the screen at a time. I have an array of all the words and definitions so python can match it for me, however, if the first word in the array does not show up, the code doesn't work. How can I bypass this error? Here is my code:

```
term = ["fug,fuge", "duc,duce,duct", "ortho", "morph", "mot,mob,mov,cine,kine", "ible, able", "flect, flex", "flu", "cide,sec,seg", "miso", "mort", "ology", "port", "ject,jet", "miss,mitt", "viv", "vert, volv, rota", "naut", "act", "klept", "frac,frag,rupt", "simil", "struct", "tens", "therm", "luc,lum,photo", "foli,phyll", "tox", "bene,bon", "agr"]
definition = ["drive away,flee", "to lead", "right,straight,correct", "change", "to move", "able to be", "to bend", "to flow", "to kill,cut", "hate", "to die", "science,study of", "carry", "to throw", "to send", "to live", "to turn", "to sail", "to do, make", "to steal", "to break", "to resemble", "to build", "to stretch", "heat", "light", "poison", "good", "field"]

x = 0

while x < 30:
    t = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), '"+term[x]+"')]")
    t.click()
    d = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), '" + definition[x] + "')]")
    d.click()

    x=x+1
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/q_hack.py", line 16, in <module>
    t = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), '"+term[x]+"')]")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(), 'fug,fuge')]"}
```

What is going on? Why is an error appearing? How can I fix it? Here is a screenshot of the page:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8dr0.png)

As you can see, not all of the 30 words are on there. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use try-except statement. It's not a really good idea to use a general except handler though.

```
term = ["fug,fuge", "duc,duce,duct", "ortho", "morph", "mot,mob,mov,cine,kine", "ible, able", "flect, flex", "flu", "cide,sec,seg", "miso", "mort", "ology", "port", "ject,jet", "miss,mitt", "viv", "vert, volv, rota", "naut", "act", "klept", "frac,frag,rupt", "simil", "struct", "tens", "therm", "luc,lum,photo", "foli,phyll", "tox", "bene,bon", "agr"]
definition = ["drive away,flee", "to lead", "right,straight,correct", "change", "to move", "able to be", "to bend", "to flow", "to kill,cut", "hate", "to die", "science,study of", "carry", "to throw", "to send", "to live", "to turn", "to sail", "to do, make", "to steal", "to break", "to resemble", "to build", "to stretch", "heat", "light", "poison", "good", "field"]

x = 0

while x < 30:
    try:
        t = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), '"+term[x]+"')]")
        t.click()
        d = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), '" + definition[x] + "')]")
        d.click()
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    x=x+1
```

Comment: You're right, so why not catch `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I forgot the complete name of the exception, sorry. Oh wait I didn't read the complete error. Edited the post

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if element exist. If it is visible click it, if not skip.
Example:

`t = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/xpath/to/your/element/here')
if t.is_displayed():
    t.click()
else:
    print "Element is not visible, or use continue if you are in for loop"`

Check documentation for more info: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed